# Overlay div doesn't prevent the next event that fired in a specific time window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my application, I add a `loaderDiv` to avoid all userevents on the page.

The loader appears. If the user force a `clickevent`(eg. greenContainer onclick) the event is fired after the loader div disappears.

I've created a short example the show you the problem

js:

```
function appendOverlay(){
    var maskDiv = $('<div id="overlay" class="loadmask" onclick:"return false;"><div class="removeDiv" onclick="sleep(3000)"><span>click to remove overlay after 3 seconds</span></div></div>');
        $('body').append(maskDiv);
    }

    function removeDiv(){
        $("#overlay").remove();
    }

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
          break;
        }
      }
      removeDiv();
    }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S9Tc9/30)**

How can I solve this problem?

---

Solved this problem by using `setTimeout(removeDiv(),0)`.
This is a problem with the event loop execution in Javascript.

Propergate the `removeDiv()` to the next tick and the userEvent `onClick()` is execute first.

[Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

[The JavaScript Event Loop](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S9Tc9/32/

Answer (score 1):

Strange 'sleep' function there.
Why don't u use the internal timeout :

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    setTimeout(function() {
         removeDiv();   
    }, milliseconds);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S9Tc9/32/)

Comment: I can't do it in async way. In this example I wait 3 second. In my application i modify data. This can take a long time (eg 3 seconds). In this time window the user must be stoped to force userevents.

Comment: U can't modify data if u hang the browser for 3 seconds with that sleep function of yours. Using this method the user can't on anything so there are no userevents?